# group by, different date

Tags: sql, oracle

I have two tabels. In first one are data for whom and when started some type of discount (there are 8 types of discounts, but we divide them for two categories). Discount is active 6 month, but decreases every month, and start date of discount is different for every person. 
In second table are transactions.

I want to know how many transaction and how high with first category of discount and second category people did in first month, second, ect.

```
SELECT (CASE  WHEN Trunc(Months_Between(A.DATE_TRANS, B.DATA_DISCOUNT))=0 THEN 0
  WHEN Trunc(Months_Between(A.DATE_TRANS, B.DATE_DISCOUNT))=1 THEN 1
  WHEN Trunc(Months_Between(A.DATE_TRANS, B.DATE_DISCOUNT))=2 THEN 2
  WHEN Trunc(Months_Between(A.DATE_TRANS, B.DATE_DISCOUNT))=3 THEN 3
  WHEN Trunc(Months_Between(A.DATE_TRANS, B.DATE_DISCOUNT))=4 THEN 4
  WHEN Trunc(Months_Between(A.DATE_TRANS, B.DATE_DISCOUNT))=5 THEN 5
  END)
  AS MONTH, 
  CASE WHEN A.TYPE IN (5,6,7,8)  THEN  COUNT(A.PRICE)
  END  AS COUNT_TRANS_1,
  CASE WHEN A.TYPE IN (5,6,7,8)  THEN  SUM(A.PRICE) 
  END AS SUM_PRICE_1,
  CASE WHEN A.TYPE IN (1,2,3,4)  THEN  COUNT(A.PRICE) 
  END AS COUNT_TRANS_2,
  CASE WHEN A.TYPE IN (1,2,3,4)  THEN  SUM(A.PRICE)
  END AS SUM_PRICE_2
from DATABASE_1 A join DATABASE_2 B
on A.ID=B.ID 
where Trunc(Months_Between(A.DATE_TRANS, B.DATE_DISCOUNT)) IN (0,1,2,3,4,5)   
GROUP BY A.ID, MONTH
```

Comment: Please post some sample data and desired result, so that your need could be clearer; among the others, why things like `WHEN Trunc(Months_Between(A.DATE_TRANS, B.DATE_DISCOUNT))=1 THEN 1`? isn't it the same than `Trunc(Months_Between(A.DATE_TRANS, B.DATE_DISCOUNT))`?

Answer (score 0):

Trying to understand your need, maybe you need the following:

```
SELECT Trunc(Months_Between(A.DATE_TRANS, B.DATE_DISCOUNT)) AS MONTH, 
  COUNT(
        CASE
            WHEN A.TYPE IN (5,6,7,8)
              THEN A.PRICE
            ELSE NULL
        END
       ) AS COUNT_TRANS_1,
  SUM(
        CASE
            WHEN A.TYPE IN (5,6,7,8) 
                THEN A.PRICE
            ELSE 0
        END
     ) AS SUM_PRICE_1,
  COUNT(
        CASE
            WHEN A.TYPE IN (1,2,3,4)
                THEN  A.PRICE
            ELSE NULL
        END
       ) AS COUNT_TRANS_2,
  SUM(
        CASE
            WHEN A.TYPE IN (1,2,3,4)
                THEN A.PRICE
            ELSE 0
        END
     ) AS SUM_PRICE_2
from DATABASE_1 A join DATABASE_2 B
on A.ID=B.ID 
where Trunc(Months_Between(A.DATE_TRANS, B.DATE_DISCOUNT)) IN (0,1,2,3,4,5)   
GROUP BY A.ID, Trunc(Months_Between(A.DATE_TRANS, B.DATE_DISCOUNT))
```

I'm not sure you need to group by ID, check it.